# Post-receive hook not using correct Ruby

Tags: rvm, git-post-receive

Please bear with me, as I am an extreme newbie and don't quite know what I'm talking about.

I'm trying to set up a Git post-receive hook to deploy my Jekyll site, as described [here](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Deployment). Its contents are

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

GIT_REPO=$HOME/git/jekyll.git
TMP_GIT_CLONE=$HOME/tmp/jekyll
PUBLIC_WWW=$HOME/public_html

echo $PATH

git clone $GIT_REPO $TMP_GIT_CLONE
cd $TMP_GIT_CLONE
echo "Run jekyll"
jekyll --no-auto $TMP_GIT_CLONE $PUBLIC_WWW
cd $HOME
echo "Remove temporary dir..."
rm -Rf $TMP_GIT_CLONE
echo "Temporary dir removed."
exit
```

I'm echoing `PATH` for troubleshooting purposes. If I login via ssh and execute the script manually with `~/git/jekyll.git/hooks/post-receive`, everything works fine, and the console reads

```sh
remote$ ~/git/jekyll.git/hooks/post-receive
/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home7/contenw6/perl5/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/home7/contenw6/perl5/bin:/ramdisk/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems/bin:/home7/contenw6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/bin
Cloning into '/home7/contenw6/tmp/jekyll'...
done.
Run jekyll
Configuration from /home7/contenw6/tmp/jekyll/_config.yml
Building site: /home7/contenw6/tmp/jekyll -> /home7/contenw6/public_html
Successfully generated site: /home7/contenw6/tmp/jekyll -> /home7/contenw6/public_html
Remove temporary dir...
Temporary dir removed.
```

However, when I `git push deploy master` from my laptop, I receive this error:

```sh
laptop$ git push deploy master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 305 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: /usr/libexec/git-core:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/ramdisk/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home7/contenw6/ruby/gems/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/bin:/home7/contenw6/.rvm/bin
remote: Cloning into '/home7/contenw6/tmp/jekyll'...
remote: done.
remote: Run jekyll
remote: /home7/contenw6/ruby/gems/gems/yajl-ruby-1.1.0/lib/yajl/yajl.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
remote: ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02
remote: 
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 14: 30293 Aborted                 jekyll --no-auto $TMP_GIT_CLONE $PUBLIC_WWW
remote: Remove temporary dir...
remote: Temporary dir removed.
To contenw6@contentioninvain.com:~/git/jekyll.git
   154f467..80c8fcb  master -> master
```

It seems to me that when the `post-receive` hook is executed as a result of `git push`, the wrong ruby (1.8.7, presumably the system's?) is being used. Note that the `PATH` variables are different in each instance.

If that's the problem, that's as much as I can figure out. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so:

1) your shebang is `/usr/bin/env sh` - this is not RVM compatible shell, either use `zsh` or `bash`

2) you need to use RVM somehow, when you login via `ssh` you already used RVM via `~/.bash_profile` but in the script you do not load RVM, try this shebang:

```
/home7/contenw6/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 1.9.3-p194
```

Comment: Thanks! This got the hook using the correct Ruby! However, now I'm getting a `Gem:LoadError`, though, and the PATH variables still aren't the same, but since that seems like a separate (albeit related) problem I'll choose this as the answer.

Comment: I think it might be still related but feel free to open new question

Answer (score 0):

The user that runs your git master doesn't have ruby setup properly with rvm.

First, you have to find out which user runs Git on the remote (it could be a user called "git"). Once you find the user, copy your `~/.rvm/` directory to that user's home directory. For example, if your username was bob, and the user running git was called gitter, then you would have to do the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/gitter/.rvm
sudo cp -R /home/bob/.rvm/ /home/gitter
```

If you don't have a .rvm directory in your home, then the following can help:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/gitter/.rvm
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I know, I run my git master on my laptop and rvm on there works fine. rvm IS messed up on the remote server (where the post-receive hook is running) and I'm not sure how to fix it, hence the question. Sorry if I can't explain it well, I'm a novice to both git and rvm.

Comment: I understand your problem, but you have to perform some steps yourself. See update to answer in a minute.